How to get the the number of data stored in the rows of an array with one formula in excel?
I just want to know how to get the number of data stored in the rows of an array with one formula.
I want to do it like this ...


=COUNTA(B2:E2)

Does this answer your question? Count non blank rows in a certain range/column Excel

Thank you sir , but your method only works for a single row , i want a formula which spills down and works for all the other rows in the given array as well

Try using BYROW()


=BYROW(B2:E6,LAMBDA(α, SUM(N(α<>""))))


Or, Use:
=BYROW(B2:E6,COUNTA)



@SuperFuture someone tagged your post as duplicate, should update your OP, that you need one single dynamic array formula and not the one which needs to fill down!
